Honest opinion on Mecway and Calculix
Currently, I am studying ANSYS for FEM analysis, but the fact that the presence of ANSYS is not guaranteed in an average company pushes me to look for free or low-cost alternatives. I found Mecway and Calculix as options.
My questions are:

For a quick comparison, if ANSYS is rated a 10 (on a scale of 1 to 10), what rating would you give to Mecway and Calculix?
Can these programs be used for professional (commercial) purposes?
(Most important for me) Are these programs suitable for composite analysis, such as CFRP?
Feel free to share your experience with these software tools; it would be very helpful.


asking for opinions is not allowed here, because there are no right and wrong opinions

try asking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

We have been using Mecway in a professional capacity at my company for 9 years. It is an excellent option, easy to use, producing results consistent with the big ticket software like ANSYS.
